# nginx exced timeout after install certbot

Tags: django, api, nginx, certificado-ssl

Tengo un servidor nginx pero tengo una cuestion, y es que no esta redireccionando las peticiones a las apps que tengo corriendo en el host, esto sucedio después de installar los certificados SSL con certbot. He intentado varias soluciones posteadas en diferentes foros pero no he sido capaz solucionar el error.

Este es el contenido de mi archivo `.conf` en la ruta `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

```
# FastAPI app

upstream backend {
   127.0.0.1:8080
}

# Django app

upstream app {
   127.0.0.1:8081
}


server {
    server_name my.appdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }


    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.api.directoryfox.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.api.directoryfox.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Antes de instalar certbot, todo funcionaba correctamente. No tengo idea de que puede ser, estaria agradecido por su ayuda.

Comment: Hi there. You are at [es.so]. Please translate you question to spanish. Bienvenido a [es.so], por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por la sugerencia ! Fue mi error no tener en cuenta el contexto, ya esta en español como debe ser. Por cierto, tienes alguna idea de que puede ser lo que no estoy teniendo encuenta respecto al servidor de nginx ?